# Wicket - set expiry date for Wicket's own resources

Tags: caching, wicket

How do I set expiry date for Wicket's own resources like wicket-ajax.js

I am having a cache problem because of migrating from an older Wicket version to a newer one but the cache is not updating with the new wicket-ajax.js resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with Wicket's IHeaderResponseDecorator or a simple Servlet Filter which is setup to run before WicketFilter and set the cache headers for all resources you want/need.